# Saving background color

Tags: java, sharedpreferences

I have an int array that holds colors, and when a button is clicked, the button chooses a random color for the background. I am having trouble saving the background color after the change is made. I go to a different fragment and come back, and its the default color. Is there any way to save the color? Perhaps with save instance or shared preference?

```
void ChangeColor()
    {
        color = new int[] {Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA,Color.DKGRAY};
        int arrLength = color.length;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rNum = rnd.nextInt(arrLength);
        view.setBackgroundColor(color[rNum]);
    }


BTN_ChangeColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UpdateScore(-100);
            ChangeColor();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 It depends on how long do you wish to have the color selected. 
 If you wish to retain the color selection even after the app has been closed and reopened android  Shared Preferences can be used.
        
        Add the following lines to your Class:
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        private void saveBackgroundColor(int selectedColor)
        {
          sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
          editor.putInt("backgroundColor", selectedColor);
          editor.commit();
        }
        private int getBackgroundColor()
        {
          SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
          return shared.getString("backgroundColor, "");
        }
        
        Also modify ChangeColor method as follows:
        
        void ChangeColor()
            {
                color = new int[] {Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA,Color.DKGRAY};
                int arrLength = color.length;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int rNum = rnd.nextInt(arrLength);
                view.setBackgroundColor(color[rNum]);
                saveBackgroundColor(color[rNum]);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had a few questions to clarify for the getBackgroundColor() method. Where would get background be called? Also when I threw it in the code It won't allow the getstring() method because the data type is an int. Would it be better to pass the shared color int and get that, or change the data type?